# parse server creates a new entry every time it's saved

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server

Here is the code when a button is tapped.

```
@IBAction func sendTapped(_ sender: Any) {
   let message = PFObject(className: "Message")
   message["sender"] = PFUser.current()?.objectId
    message["recipient"] = recipientObjectId

    message.addUniqueObject(messageTextField.text, forKey: "messages")
    message.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) in
        if success {
            print("did it save?")
        }
    })
```

}

Everytime the button is pressed, it creates a new Objectid in the parse server dashboard.  How do I make it so it uses the same ObjectId, and messages keep adding to the messages array?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

**Updating Objects**

> Updating an object is simple. Just set some new data on it and call
>   one of the save methods. Assuming you have saved the object and have
>   the objectId, you can retrieve the PFObject using a PFQuery and update
>   its data:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("xWMyZEGZ") {
  (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error != nil {
    print(error)
  } else if let gameScore = gameScore {
    gameScore["cheatMode"] = true
    gameScore["score"] = 1338
    gameScore.saveInBackground()
  }
```

More here in [Parse-update-Docs](http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#updating-objects)